# this.getParams() firing once Not updating the states on Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router. Where I pass the states in routing section . But router is updating the params only first time 
[Here is fiddle link for code](http://jsfiddle.net/k62yLz1y/1/)
This is Table Class

```
var Table = React.createClass({
         mixins: [ Router.State ],
        getInitialState: function() {
                                    var table;
                                    var table_id = this.getParams().table_id;
                                    console.log(table_id);
                                    tables.forEach(function(model) {
                                      if(model.id == table_id) {
                                        console.log(model);
                                        table = model;
                                      }
                                    });
                                    return {
                                      table: table
                                    }
                                }
```

})

And here is the router

```
var routes = (
      <Route handler={Tables} path="/">
        <DefaultRoute handler={Index} />
        <Route name="table" path="/table/:table_id" handler={Table}/>
      </Route>
    );
   ReactRouter.run(routes, function (Handler) {
      React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
   });
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the tables class:

```
var Tables = React.createClass({
    indexTemplate: function() {
      return <h2>Please select a table</h2>
    },
    render: function() {
            var links = tables.map(function(table) {
              return <Link to="table" params= {{ table_id:table.id}} className="panel six columns" key={table.id}>{table.id}</Link>
            });
          return (
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="twelve rows">
                      <h1>Ordr</h1>
                      <hr />
                      <div className="row">
                        <div id="tables" className="four columns">
                          <h2>Tables</h2>
                          {links}
                        </div>
                        <div id="order" className="eight columns">
                          <RouteHandler/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )
              }
           });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be some code where you nest your `Table` component within `Tables` component like this:

```
<ReactRouter.RouteHandler {...this.props} key={this.props.params.tableId}/>
```

If you dont specify the `key` property and you route between different tables, say `/table/1` and `/table/2`, the `Table` component is not mounted and unmounted, just re-rendered. Therefore `getInitialState` method is not fired.

---

**UPDATE**

You should change this line in your fiddle (line 43):

```
<RouteHandler />
```

to

```
<RouteHandler key={this.props.params.table_id}/>
// table_id name comes from this definition: <Route name="table" path="/table/:table_id" handler={Table}/>
```

working fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/t4hvuu0r/

Comment: Thank you - this fixed an issue I was having as well!